# How to get the request ID of a SNMP packet in Python

Tags: python, snmp

Which SNMP library offers an API to get single properties of captured (tcpdump) SNMP packets like the request-ID or the protocol version?

I found that pySNMP offers such a low-level API but only for v1/v2c versions. But I need both v2c and v3.

Answer (score 0):

what exactly you want to know.  whether :
 python net-snmp api supports v3 or not 
or
oid for finding request-id of a snmp packet

Comment: Neither. The request-id is a field within a SNMP get-request or get-response packet. I was searching for an API that allows to instantiate an object from captured binary data and then read single fields from that object (packet).